# Is it possible to get the machine name of the node a test executes on using selenium grid?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I've been looking at the documentation and been unable to get information such as the machine name / IP for the executing node.

Is it possible to get this information using the C# bindings, I feel I must be missing something as I'd expect the RemoteWebDriver to expose this information.

Cheers,
Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The details are given in this gist (compiled by K.R.Mahadevan). You can see the c# code snippet in the comments

https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/1766772

```
string url = "http://localhost:4444/grid/api/testsession?session=" + this.SessionId;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
string host = new Uri(jObject.GetValue("proxyId").ToString()).Host;
stream.Close();

Console.WriteLine(host);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get machine name.

For Machine Name:

```
String name = Environment.UserName;
```

For IP address

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I know how to get the machine name and IP. The question asks specifically via Selenium Grid.

Note the second option also assumes I am running under a web context, presumably an ASP.Net website.